# ¿Cómo podria ordenar el array que devueve listFiles() con las carpetas primero?

Tags: java, array

El siguiente código imprime por pantalla el listado del directorio ordenado alfabeticamente

```
public static void muestraInfoRuta(File ruta) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //¿Existe?
        if(ruta.exists()){
            if(ruta.isFile()){
                //Es un archivo
                System.out.println("El nombre del archivo es: "+ruta.getName());
            }else if(ruta.isDirectory()){
                //Es un directorio/carpeta
                File[] lista = ruta.listFiles();
                System.out.println("Listado del directorio: ");
                for(File f : lista){
                    System.out.println(f.isDirectory()?"[D] ":"[A] "+f.getName());
                }
            }
        }else{
            //No existe
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

Me gustaria que las carpetas salgan primero, y los archivos después. Tampoco entiendo por que el nombre de las carpetas no se imprime correctamente, dejo la salida del programa:

Listado del directorio:
[A] alumnos_notas.txt
[A] diccionario.txt
[D]
[A] frases.txt
[D]
[A] numeros.txt
[A] pi-million.txt
[A] usa_apellidos.txt
[A] usa_nombres.txt
[A] usa_personas.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te imprime los nombres de los directorios porque sencillamente no se los estas agregando

```
System.out.println(f.isDirectory()?"[D] ":"[A] "+f.getName()); //Así lo tienes
System.out.println(f.isDirectory()?"[D] "+f.getName():"[A] "+f.getName()); //Así debería estar
//------------------Esto falto--------------↑
```

Ahora para mostrar primero las carpetas y luego los ficheros, creo que lo más fácil es hacer 2 for:

```
File[] lista = ruta.listFiles();
System.out.println("Listado del directorio: ");

for(File f : lista){
  if(f.isDirectory()){
     System.out.println("[D] " + f.getName());
  }             
}
for(File f : lista){
  if(f.isFile()){
     System.out.println("[A] " + f.getName());
  }             
}
```